# Comparing two arrays for the same values and non-matching values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, comparison

I am trying to compare two arrays and display different results if there are matching values or not.

```
@codes.each do |code|
  accessible_codes = code.roles.pluck(:role_id)
  current_users_roles = current_user.roles.pluck(:role_id)

  (accessible_codes & current_users_roles).each {|i|
    if i
      puts "accessible"
    else
      puts "not accessible"
    end
  }
end
```

Currently I only get the "accessible" output. How do I compare each and get both true and false cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the intersection of those two arrays. It sounds like you want to check whether or not there are any elements in that intersection. You'd want something like this:

```
current_users_roles = current_user.roles.pluck(:role_id)
@codes.each do |code|
  accessible_codes = code.roles.pluck(:role_id)
  if (accessible_codes & current_users_roles).empty?
    puts "not accessible"
  else
    puts "accessible"
  end
end
```